# Electron js offline network with pouchdb

Tags: networking, electron, couchdb, pouchdb

I've created an electronjs app with pouchdb. The intent of this desktop app is to work within a wireless network of tablet application that share the same data that is pretty much blocked from the internet 95% of the time (hence the pouchdb implementation). In order for the tablet applications to sync with the desktop app, they need to be aware of how to connect to the desktop app within the network. My initial thought would be to broadcast the IP address of the electron js app in order to share data within pouchdb, but I'm not sure if it's possible. I am also thinking that I'll could install couchdb as a separate instance on the network, but would like to keep set up as simple as possible. Any ideas on how I can set this up with electron js and pouchdb?

Comment: I would think setting up CouchDb or PouchDb Server on the desktop machine or somewhere else on the network would be the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to achieve the desired result using the [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) discovery service with Node. With mDNS, you can query the local network for other devices broadcasting on a specific namespace (e.g. 'myappid.local') which the application could query the network for.

[multicast-dns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multicast-dns) is a module capable of querying the network for other devices broadcasting under a name and getting their local IP address.

After establishing a connection to other application instances on the same network, you could try replicating the database over that connection. A PouchDB plugin might be required for getting this data from Electron's main process to the renderer.